# Changing a product's Tax Category ID onSaveProduct event

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-craftcommerce

I'm trying to alter a products tax category whenever it's saved based on a condition.

```
craft()->on('commerce_products.onSaveProduct', function(Event $event){
    $product = $event->params['product'];
    $criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
    $criteria->id = $product->productFilterArtist[0]->id;
    $artist = $criteria->first();

    //Craft::dd($product->taxCategoryId); // 2

    if ($artist->getContent()->vatRegistered) {
        $product->taxCategoryId = 1;
        //Craft::dd($product->taxCategoryId); // 1
    }

    $success = craft()->elements->saveElement($product);

    //Craft::dd($product->taxCategoryId); // 1
});
```

It appears to work as the output of each `Craft::dd` is correct. However the entry still shows the original tax category in the CP.

I have been able to alter the shipping category in the same way without trouble. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the new field value `onSaveProduct` meant that the only the general element and its custom field data was being saved and not the tax ID on the product model.

To solve this, the `onBeforeSaveProduct` event should be used. This allows modification of the product model before it's saved.

```
craft()->on('commerce_products.onBeforeSaveProduct', function(Event $event){
    $product = $event->params['product'];
    $criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
    $criteria->id = $product->productFilterArtist[0]->id;
    $artist = $criteria->first();
    if ($artist && $artist->getContent()->vatRegistered) {
        $product->taxCategoryId = 1;
    }
})
```